# sklearn and statsmodels getting very different logistic regression results

Tags: scikit-learn, logistic-regression, statsmodels

```py
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
    

TESTDATA = StringIO(""",age,age2,gender,average,hypertension
0,61,3721,0,0.068025807,FALSE 1,52,2704,0,0.066346102,FALSE
2,59,3481,0,0.068163704,FALSE 3,47,2209,0,0.062870186,FALSE
4,57,3249,0,0.065415069,TRUE 5,50,2500,1,0.06260146,FALSE
6,44,1936,0,0.067612307,FALSE 7,60,3600,0,0.062675767,FALSE
8,60,3600,0,0.063555558,TRUE 9,65,4225,0,0.066346102,FALSE
10,61,3721,0,0.068163704,FALSE 11,52,2704,0,0.062870186,FALSE
12,59,3481,0,0.065415069,FALSE 13,47,2209,0,0.06260146,FALSE
14,57,2209,0,0.067612307,TRUE 15,50,3249,1,0.067612307,FALSE
16,44,2500,0,0.067612307,FALSE 17,50,1936,0,0.062675767,FALSE
18,44,3600,0,0.063555558,FALSE 19,60,3600,0,0.066346102,TRUE
20,60,4225,0,0.068163704,TRUE 21,65,3721,0,0.062870186,TRUE
22,61,3600,0,0.065415069,FALSE 23,52,3600,0,0.06260146,FALSE
24,57,4225,0,0.067612307,FALSE 25,50,2209,1,0.066346102,TRUE
26,44,3249,0,0.068163704,FALSE 27,60,2500,0,0.062870186,FALSE
28,60,1936,0,0.065415069,FALSE 29,60,3600,0,0.06260146,FALSE
30,65,3600,0,0.067612307,FALSE 31,61,4225,0,0.066346102,FALSE
32,52,3721,0,0.068163704,TRUE 33,59,2704,0,0.062870186,FALSE
34,47,3249,0,0.065415069,FALSE 35,57,2500,1,0.06260146,TRUE
36,50,1936,0,0.067612307,FALSE 37,60,3600,0,0.062675767,FALSE
38,57,3600,0,0.063555558,FALSE 39,50,4225,0,0.067508574,FALSE
40,44,3721,0,0.068163704,TRUE 41,50,3600,0,0.066346102,FALSE
42,44,3600,0,0.068163704,FALSE 43,60,4225,0,0.062870186,TRUE
44,60,3600,0,0.065415069,TRUE 45,33,4225,1,0.06260146,TRUE
46,44,3721,0,0.067612307,FALSE 47,60,2704,0,0.067508574,FALSE
48,60,3600,0,0.068025807,FALSE 49,65,4225,0,0.066346102,FALSE
50,61,3721,0,0.068163704,FALSE 51,52,3600,0,0.062870186,TRUE
52,60,3600,0,0.065415069,FALSE 53,65,4225,0,0.066346102,FALSE
54,61,2209,0,0.062870186,TRUE 55,52,3600,1,0.065415069,FALSE
56,59,4225,0,0.068163704,FALSE 57,47,3721,0,0.062870186,FALSE
58,57,3600,0,0.065415069,TRUE 59,50,3600,0,0.06260146,FALSE
60,44,4225,0,0.067612307,FALSE 61,60,3721,0,0.066346102,FALSE
62,34,1936,0,0.068163704,FALSE 63,59,3600,0,0.062870186,FALSE
64,47,3600,0,0.065415069,TRUE 65,57,4225,1,0.06260146,FALSE
66,56,1936,0,0.067612307,FALSE 67,56,2209,0,0.062675767,FALSE
68,60,3249,0,0.063555558,FALSE 69,65,2500,0,0.067508574,FALSE""")

    
df = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, sep=",")
    
print(sm.Logit(endog=df["hypertension"], exog=df[[ "age", "age2", "gender","average"]]).fit( disp=False).params)
print(LogisticRegression(fit_intercept = False, C = 1e9).fit( df[[ "age", "age2", "gender","average"]],df["hypertension"]).coef_)
```

The results are completely different:

```
age         0.011864
age2        0.000294
gender      1.015793
average   -44.285129
```

```
[[-2.69997534e-02  8.27509854e-05  7.92208243e-01 -2.28174015e-02]]
```

Meanwhile, the results are the same for linear regression.

```
print(sm.OLS(endog=df["a"], exog=df[["b","c"]]).fit( disp=False).params)
print(LinearRegression(fit_intercept = False).fit( df[["b","c"]],df["a"]).coef_)
```

Results:

```
age        0.002484
age2       0.000050
gender     0.223877
average   -1.235937
```

```
[ 2.48380428e-03  4.98449037e-05  2.23877433e-01 -1.23593682e+00]
```

Why is that? It's really puzzling...

Comment: In what sense are the Logit results completely different? These values are nearly the same (4 d.p.). The small differences are driven by the stopping criteria used by the two packages. Logit models are non-linear and do not admit a closed-form solution for the parameter estimator.

Comment: @KevinS Sorry there is something wrong with my question. To be corrected.

Comment: @KevinS I have updated the question. Can you have a look please?

Comment: With only 1 true value in hypertension your model appears to not be point identified, and so there are many sets of parameters that will produce the same fit. In fact, the fit produced by the two as measured by the log-likelihood evaluated at the fitted values is identical.

Comment: @KevinS My full dataset contains nearly 50k data yet they are still very different. I will add more data for illustration. Also, why would Linear Regression results are the same?

Comment: @KevinS Can you have a look please? The logit results are completely different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

scikit-learn isn't finding the best objective value here. statsmodels does a better job in this particular example.  The only difference appears to be the choice of the optimizer, and if statsmodels is forced to use the same choice as SK learn, then the estimated parameter values are the same.

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LogisticRegression
from io import StringIO
import pandas as pd
import statsmodels.api as sm
    

TESTDATA = StringIO(""",age,age2,gender,average,hypertension
0,61,3721,0,0.068025807,FALSE 1,52,2704,0,0.066346102,FALSE
2,59,3481,0,0.068163704,FALSE 3,47,2209,0,0.062870186,FALSE
4,57,3249,0,0.065415069,TRUE 5,50,2500,1,0.06260146,FALSE
6,44,1936,0,0.067612307,FALSE 7,60,3600,0,0.062675767,FALSE
8,60,3600,0,0.063555558,TRUE 9,65,4225,0,0.066346102,FALSE
10,61,3721,0,0.068163704,FALSE 11,52,2704,0,0.062870186,FALSE
12,59,3481,0,0.065415069,FALSE 13,47,2209,0,0.06260146,FALSE
14,57,2209,0,0.067612307,TRUE 15,50,3249,1,0.067612307,FALSE
16,44,2500,0,0.067612307,FALSE 17,50,1936,0,0.062675767,FALSE
18,44,3600,0,0.063555558,FALSE 19,60,3600,0,0.066346102,TRUE
20,60,4225,0,0.068163704,TRUE 21,65,3721,0,0.062870186,TRUE
22,61,3600,0,0.065415069,FALSE 23,52,3600,0,0.06260146,FALSE
24,57,4225,0,0.067612307,FALSE 25,50,2209,1,0.066346102,TRUE
26,44,3249,0,0.068163704,FALSE 27,60,2500,0,0.062870186,FALSE
28,60,1936,0,0.065415069,FALSE 29,60,3600,0,0.06260146,FALSE
30,65,3600,0,0.067612307,FALSE 31,61,4225,0,0.066346102,FALSE
32,52,3721,0,0.068163704,TRUE 33,59,2704,0,0.062870186,FALSE
34,47,3249,0,0.065415069,FALSE 35,57,2500,1,0.06260146,TRUE
36,50,1936,0,0.067612307,FALSE 37,60,3600,0,0.062675767,FALSE
38,57,3600,0,0.063555558,FALSE 39,50,4225,0,0.067508574,FALSE
40,44,3721,0,0.068163704,TRUE 41,50,3600,0,0.066346102,FALSE
42,44,3600,0,0.068163704,FALSE 43,60,4225,0,0.062870186,TRUE
44,60,3600,0,0.065415069,TRUE 45,33,4225,1,0.06260146,TRUE
46,44,3721,0,0.067612307,FALSE 47,60,2704,0,0.067508574,FALSE
48,60,3600,0,0.068025807,FALSE 49,65,4225,0,0.066346102,FALSE
50,61,3721,0,0.068163704,FALSE 51,52,3600,0,0.062870186,TRUE
52,60,3600,0,0.065415069,FALSE 53,65,4225,0,0.066346102,FALSE
54,61,2209,0,0.062870186,TRUE 55,52,3600,1,0.065415069,FALSE
56,59,4225,0,0.068163704,FALSE 57,47,3721,0,0.062870186,FALSE
58,57,3600,0,0.065415069,TRUE 59,50,3600,0,0.06260146,FALSE
60,44,4225,0,0.067612307,FALSE 61,60,3721,0,0.066346102,FALSE
62,34,1936,0,0.068163704,FALSE 63,59,3600,0,0.062870186,FALSE
64,47,3600,0,0.065415069,TRUE 65,57,4225,1,0.06260146,FALSE
66,56,1936,0,0.067612307,FALSE 67,56,2209,0,0.062675767,FALSE
68,60,3249,0,0.063555558,FALSE 69,65,2500,0,0.067508574,FALSE""")

    
df = pd.read_csv(TESTDATA, sep=",")


mod = sm.Logit(endog=df["hypertension"], exog=df[[ "age", "age2", "gender","average"]])
sk_mod = LogisticRegression(fit_intercept = False, C = 1e9).fit( df[[ "age", "age2", "gender","average"]],df["hypertension"])

res_default = mod.fit(np.squeeze(sk_mod.coef_), disp=False)
res_lbfgs= mod.fit(np.squeeze(sk_mod.coef_), method="lbfgs", disp=False)

print("The default optimizer produces a larger log-likelihood (the optimization target)")
print(f"Default: {res_default.llf}, LBFGS: {res_lbfgs.llf}")
print("LBFGS is identical to SK Learn")
print(f"SK Learn coef\n {np.squeeze(sk_mod.coef_)}")
print(f"LBFGS coef \n {np.asarray(res_lbfgs.params)}")
print("The default optimizer produces different estimates")
print(f"Default coef \n {np.asarray(res_default.params)}")


res_lbfgs_sv= mod.fit(res_default.params, method="lbfgs", disp=False)
print(f"LBFGS with better starting parameters matches the default\n {np.asarray(res_lbfgs_sv.params)}")
```

Running the code produces

```
The default optimizer produces a larger log-likelihood (the optimization target)
Default: -15.853969516447952, LBFGS: -16.30414297615966
LBFGS is identical to SK Learn
SK Learn coef
 [-4.42216394e-02  2.23648541e-04  1.19470339e+00 -4.28565669e-03]
LBFGS coef
 [-4.42216394e-02  2.23648541e-04  1.19470339e+00 -4.28565669e-03]
The default optimizer produces different estimates
Default coef
 [ 1.33419520e-02  4.79332044e-04  1.69742850e+00 -6.53888649e+01]
LBFGS with better starting parameters matches the default
 [ 1.33419520e-02  4.79332044e-04  1.69742850e+00 -6.53888649e+01]
```